# how can i avoid duplicate field in jackson when serialising bidirectional relation

Tags: java, spring

im using Jackson 2.13.0 & Spring Boot i want to serialise My Pojo PhaseProject :

```
@Entity
@Data @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(include= JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT,use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
public class ProjectPhase {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id_phase;
    private String phaseName;
    private Date dateDebt;
    private Date dateFin;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "projectPhase")
    private List<TypePhase> typesPhase;
    @ManyToOne
    private Project project;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "projectPhase")
    private List<Collab_Task_ProjectPhase> collab_task_projectPhases;
}
```

Project Phase List output :

```
[
  {
    "ProjectPhase": {
      "id_phase": 1,
      "phaseName": "phase1",
      "dateDebt": null,
      "dateFin": null,
      "typesPhase": [],
      "project": {
        "Project": {
          "id": 1,
          "actif": true,
          "dateDebut": "2022-06-03T10:13:02.975+00:00",
          "dateFin": null,
          "projectName": "project 1"
        }
      },
      "collab_task_projectPhases": []
    }
  },
  {
    "ProjectPhase": {
      "id_phase": 2,
      "phaseName": "phase2",
      "dateDebt": null,
      "dateFin": null,
      "typesPhase": [],
      "project": {
        "Project": {
          "id": 1,
          "actif": true,
          "dateDebut": "2022-06-03T10:13:02.975+00:00",
          "dateFin": null,
          "projectName": "project 1"
        }
      },
      "collab_task_projectPhases": []
    }
  }
]
```

Project Class :

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@JsonRootName(value = "project")
@JsonTypeInfo(include= JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT,use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
public class Project implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String ProjectName;
    private boolean actif;
    private Date dateDebut;
    private Date dateFin;
    //Status Enum (Dev Liv ...)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<ProjectPhase> projectPhases;

}
```

My probleme is how can i avoid serialisising project in ProjectPhase:

"project": {
"Project": {
"id": 1,
}
}

how can i avoid  duplicate field in jackson when serialising  bidirectional  relation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved this issue by adding ProjectDTO and associated @JsonSerializer

ProjectDTO class :

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonSerialize(using = ProjectDtoSerializer.class)
//@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
public class ProjectDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private boolean actif;
    private Date dateDebut;
    private Date dateFin;
    private ProjectPhaseStatus status;
    private List<ProjectPhaseDTO> projectPhaseDTOS;
}
```

ProjectDtoSerializer class :

```
public class ProjectDtoSerializer extends StdSerializer<ProjectDTO> {

    public ProjectDtoSerializer(){
        this(null);
    }

    public ProjectDtoSerializer(Class<ProjectDTO> t) {
        super(t);
    }
    @Override
    public void serialize(ProjectDTO projectDTO, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("project");
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("name",projectDTO.getName());
        jsonGenerator.writeBooleanField("actif",projectDTO.isActif());
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("dateDebut",projectDTO.getDateDebut().toString());
        if(projectDTO.getDateFin()!=null) jsonGenerator.writeStringField("dateFin",projectDTO.getDateFin().toString());
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("status",projectDTO.getStatus().toString());
        jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("projectPhase");
        jsonGenerator.writeStartArray();
        projectDTO.getProjectPhaseDTOS().forEach(projectPhaseDTO -> {
            try {
                jsonGenerator.writeObject(projectPhaseDTO);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        jsonGenerator.writeEndArray();
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();

        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Thanks for help